# How hypervisor design changes when hardware support is provided in processor?

Tags: linux-kernel, hypervisor

I would like to know how hypervisor design changes or how functionality improves when hardware support is provided from processor,as I know ARM CORTEX A9 series doesn't have support for virtualization from processor and this is expected in ARM CORTEX A-15 onwards, my question is how this differs in implementation and what is this hardware support in general means? and what components specific to hypervisor software which H/W take care of ?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 0):

basically in order to understand changes in implementation of hypervisor when a processor supports virtualization requires to understand what is hardware virtualization. hardware extensions convert non privileged but sensitive instructions(e.g. popf) of ISA privileged in sense these instructions cause trap to hypervisor. This is basic concept for virtualizable hardware. but with passage of time vendors introduced new functionality regarding virtualization. the most important was nested paging (EPT/NPT) in order to efficiently virtualize memory. presently hardware has been revolutionized as compared to late 90s.

so when there were no hardware facilities, VMware team still manage to virtualize the hardware. they made use of binary translation and dynamic interpretor for non virtualizeable part of ISA. for memory they used shadow page tables(sPT) to virtualize memory. In sPT, processor use sPT instead of guest tables (as MMU can scan one level of tables). In EPT/NPT, MMU take two rounds of table first for guest tables and then for EPT/NPT. By this method, efficiency is increased in most use cases. when hypervisor use hardware virtualization extensions then it use hardware defined structures(second level tables,VMCS) in the strict manner. I am feeling difficulty to conclude the answer due to broad scope of the question but I hope this answer will provide sufficient material to start up